# Чем можно заменить метод VkApi messages.getChatUsers?

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api, бот

На странице метода написано:

> Данный метод устарел и может быть отключён через некоторое время,
> пожалуйста, избегайте его использования.

Чем можно заменить? Необходимо получить список id'шников пользователей беседы

Answer (score 1):

[`getConversationMembers`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversationMembers) - Позволяет получить список участников беседы